# How to print full Arraylist which is stored in a HashMap

Tags: arraylist, hashmap, key, multimap, getvalue

I need some assistance to get my assignment working. 
Goal is to get a shopping cart which is used by different buyer and everybody can add some article to his shopping cart. My idea is to create an arraylist of all articles I put into the shopping cart and map the created arraylist with the hashmap key, string name of the buyer.

Unfortunatelly If I wanna print out the articles for each buyer, I even get all articles of all buyers. To be honest I'm quite new to this and still unsure if this is the right way to get this working. Before I tried Hasmap I wanted to have dynamic name of my arraylists, means the name of the arraylist of article should be the buyer name.

```
public class Main {

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        int amount;
        String customerName = "";       
        System.out.println("Wieviel Benutzer möchten einkaufen?");
        amount = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            System.out.println("Name eingeben:");
            customerName = sc.nextLine();
            Warenkorb.initialCreation(customerName);}}}         

class Warenkorb {
private static ArrayList<Artikel> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<>();
private static HashMap<String, ArrayList<Artikel>> map = new 
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Artikel>>();
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void initialCreation(String customerName) {
    String currentUser = customerName;
    int amountofitem;
    System.out.println("How many Arcticle do you want to create");
    amountofitem = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

for (int i = 0; i < amountofitem; i++) {
    String artikelName = "";
    int price, qty;
    System.out.println(">>>Add Article<<<");
    System.out.println("Please enter article name");
    artikelName = sc.nextLine().trim().toString();
    System.out.println("Please enter price");
    price = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please enter how many you would like to add -> quantity");
    qty = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    Artikel bla = new Artikel(artikelName, qty, price);
    shoppingCart.add(bla);
    }
    map.put(currentUser, shoppingCart);

for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Artikel>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
System.out.println("Shopping Cart of  " + entry.getKey());
    for (Artikel item : entry.getValue()) {
    System.out.println("Artikel" + " " + item.getItemName() + " " + item.getItemPrice() + "€ " + item.getItemTax() + "%.");
    }
}
}
```

This is what I get if I try to print out each shoppingcart:

```
Shopping Cart of PEter
Artikel Apfel 3€ 3%.
Artikel Banana 3€ 3%.
Shopping Cart of  Chris
Artikel Apfel 3€ 3%.
Artikel Banana 3€ 3%.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `shoppingCart` and `map` are defined in static context of the class. Every time you call `initialCreation` method it deals with the same collections. I'd suggest to make collections non-static and `initialCreated` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int amount;
    String customerName = "";
    System.out.println("Wieviel Benutzer möchten einkaufen?");
    amount = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name eingeben:");
        customerName = sc.nextLine();
        new Warenkorb().initialCreation(customerName);
    }
}
```

}

```
class Warenkorb {
private ArrayList<String> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<>();
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void initialCreation(String customerName) {
   // you code
}
```

}

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have changed what you proposed. Now I create a new Warenkorb().initialCreation(customerName); I also changed everything to non static in my Warenkorb class. initialCreation was already a mehtod, therefore I didn't changed anything here. But the access to the arraylist is still a big question mark for me, if I try to print the array. This is my current code, but this access only to the last created shopping cart :(

Comment: `for (HashMap.Entry<String, ArrayList<Artikel>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println("Shopping Cart of  " + entry.getKey());
   
   for (Artikel item : entry.getValue()) {
    System.out.println("Artikel" + " " + item.getItemName() + " " + item.getItemPrice() + "€ " + item.getItemTax() + "%.");
   }
  }`